# PHP how to connect two players

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm making a website. and one of the features i want it to have is to have a simple game that connects 2 players together. my problem is I don't know how to make it so both player are in the same "room" because on room holds only 2 players. 
On way i approached this is once one player joined, he gets a "wait for next player" message and waits while sending to the database that one player have joined. how do i make it keep checking  for the next 3 minutes if the next player joined?

**UPDATE**

First here is the code so far:

```
<html>
<title>SiteName (test)</title>
<head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$u

sername = 
$password = 
$dbname = 

try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM game');
$stmt->execute(array('gameID' => $gameID));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br />\n";

 }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="w">Look for Game</button><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="lbl" class="button"></a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var elem = document.getElementById("w").innerHTML = "Wait";
var counter = 10;
var label= document.getElementById("lbl");
var counter = 10;
var clabel= document.createElement("p");
clabel.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;

label.parentNode.replaceChild(clabel, label);

id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        clabel.parentNode.replaceChild(label, clabel);
        clearInterval(id);

    } else {
        clabel.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
}, 1000);
  }
 </script>

<?php 
$conn = null;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Am trying to make it so that if the first player joined, he will be waiting (i have it for 10 seconds here as a test) until the other joins. the way am trying to do it is to have a field in the database will know if the a player is in that page and await the next player. I read something about long polling but not sure how to implement it for my case.

Any feed back would be helpful, Thank you

Comment: You're probably looking for a web socket.

Comment: If you insist on keeping players and rooms in db, and to connect players in PHP only (without IPC or websockets, etc), then you need a loop like `for (10 times) { sleep(1 second); if (select_players_in_this_room() == 2) {print "ok"; return;} }` where one player (aka http request aka php process) waits for another player.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not the best language to do this in, but if you still want to do it.

Look into using Ratchet (http://socketo.me/), which is a PHP websocket library. A websocket is full duplex, meaning that a connection between the server and client is kept open. Game state and player actions can then be communicated through this.

http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world is an example you can learn from.

Comment: Going to look into right now, thank you for feed back

Answer (score 0):

first you will want javascript or some client side code to handle this. as php will execute on the server side then display to the user. if you use ajax with javascript you can get the client side and server side to work together.

you will want to use a while loop, in this loop you will set a [timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

in the while loop you can call the [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp) script you want untill you get your result you want. I'm assuming you plan on making this a turn by turn game for the players. you will want a table that sets "true" to if player 1 or player 2 are in the game. if both are turn then the game begins.

Hope this logic helps